# How to solve: "Error: object 'py' not found" in Rmarkdown when calling variable form python chunk to R chunk

Tags: r-markdown, reticulate

I am using R markdown and reticulate package.After running a simple 2 line python code in a chunk,I cant use the python variable in the R chunk using the py$x function.I get the following error:
"Error: object 'py' not found"

I have already tried another function py_to_r for converting python objects to R but even that doesnt work cause it throws an error that it cant find the object.I am including python configuration also:

````
    ```{r}
    py_config()
    ```


python:         C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/chatsh02/AppData/Local/CONTIN~1/ANACON~1/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1
version:        3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.2

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\Users\chatsh02\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe


```{r}
library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv('r-reticulate')
py_available(TRUE)
```

```{python}
a=7
print(a)
```

```{r}
py$a
```
````

Expected results should be I should be getting R variable a with value 7.Actual result: Error: object 'py' not found

Answer (score 5):

I got this because I forgot to run `library(reticulate)` inside my Rmarkdown Document. It looks like you have it, but just make sure you actually run that line.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to call the reticulate package in the same chunk, that works for me.

```
library(reticulate)
py$a
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to knit your document, then everything works fine. Executing the single chunks will not work, just by knitting them to HTML, PDF or whatever.

[image]